# Is it possible to disable HDMI Auto-sense after a Display connects? xrandr?

Tags: display

I'm using Ubuntu Studio 20.04 (xfce) with the standard packaged video drivers. On system start I have it running the following command to assign the ports of my three cards, two HDMI and one DVI port:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-A-0 --output DVI-D-0 --output HDMI-A-1-1 --same-as HDMI-A-0
```

One of my HDMI ports is connected to a 8 port HDMI splitter. Whenever I cycle the power to one of the 8 displays, all of the other displays connected to the splitter loose the video and audio as the OS renegotiates communication to the cycled monitor. After several seconds they all settle out and display the correct video and audio.

I then modified the above command by adding mode and rate:

```
xrandr --output HDMI-A-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.94 --output DVI-D-0 --output HDMI-A-1-1 --same-as HDMI-A-0 --mode 1920x1080 --rate 59.94
```

No change. Any thoughts on how to disable the auto display settings and setting manually so the other displays don't blank out?

Comment: Just wondering, did you manage to find a solution?